# QToolButton - html text

Tags: qt

Is it possible to format `QToolButton` text with HTML like in `QLabel`? `toolbutton.SetText("Text <b>Test</b>")` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without subclassing `QToolButton` and overriding the `paintEvent`, but if you just want to style the text in the button, you can use [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet.html) like this:

```
toolButton->setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold");
```