# QToolButton doesn't support HTML

Tags: html, c++, qt

I want to use HTML format in `QToolButton`.  for example in this picture , I should create `QToolButton` in "Sara" and "Online".

[image]

Here is my code:

```
viewControl=new QToolButton(this);
QString labelText = "<P><b><i><FONT COLOR='#fff'>";
labelText .append("Sara");
labelText .append("</i></b></P></br>");
labelText .append("online");
viewControl->setText(labelText);
```

But it seems `QToolButton` cannot define HTML format.
[image]

How to resolve it?

I also used layout in `QToolButton` but it show me empty box.

```
QVBoxLayout *titleLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
QLabel *nameLabel = new QLabel("Name");
QLabel *onlineLabel = new QLabel ("online");
titleLayout->addWidget(nameLabel);
titleLayout->addWidget(onlineLabel);
viewControl->setLayout(titleLayout);
```

Comment: Why do you suppose you can use html inside a QToolButton ?

Comment: I've used html inside QLabel and I think I can use it inside QToolButton. @perencia

Comment: Have you tried this? http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtpushbutton.html

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852340/two-colours-text-in-qpushbutton)

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600281/qtoolbutton-html-text)

I don't think this is possible without subclassing QToolButton and overriding the paintEvent. but you can try something like this:

```
toolButton->setStyleSheet("font-weight: Italic");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , Although I want to create multiple line in QToolButton. and it's not help me to do that.